# Cannot use python-nmap

Tags: python, nmap

I have multiple times installed python-nmap following the instructions on their site, but it just doesn't work. Every time I try to test it by doing:

```
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

I get the following error:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "nmap/nmap.py", line 118, in __init__
    p = subprocess.Popen(['nmap', '-V'], bufsize=10000, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never installed `nmap`. What Linux distro are you running?

Comment: @Blender I am running ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install nmap`

Comment: @Blender Yeah, that did it. As stupid as it might sound I didn't know I needed nmap in order to use python-nmap. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This error is fixed if you install a later version of nmap for python 2.*
Follow the link here: http://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to install nmap by the looks of it

Comment: Why was I down arrowed?